# Calculate the sum of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (-1)^n \frac{n+1}{3^n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Currently going through old Analysis I - exams and I'm having a problem witht his one:

> Calculate the sum of the series: $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (-1)^n \frac{n+1}{3^n}$$

What I did was firstly to rearrange the sequence:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (-1)^n \frac{n+1}{3^n} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (n+1) \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n $$
But with $(n+1)$ I cannot apply the formula for a geometric series, and I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Hints: Let the sum denote by $S$. Investigate $S-\frac13S$.

Comment: See also [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\left| x\right|\lt 1$ you can write

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1} = x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}\tag{1}$$
Now it must hold
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(n+1\right)x^n =\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n+1} \stackrel{(1)}{=}\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

Thus for $x=-\frac{1}{3}$ 
you will get

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(n+1\right)\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n = \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)^2} = \frac{9}{16}$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{3^n}=f\left(-\frac13\right),
$$
with
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n.
$$
For every $x\in (-1,1)$ we have
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n=
\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \quad \forall x\in (-1,1).
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{3^n}=\frac{1}{(1+1/3)^2}=\frac{9}{16}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The general method to attack this kind of problem is to use power series, as in the other answers. But for this particular problem, no such machinery is necessary, as hinted by JLamprong in the comments.

Indeed, calculating $S+S/3$ one gets
$$
S+\frac{S}3=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{3^n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{3^{n+1}}\\
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{3^n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n}{3^{n}}\\
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{3^n}=\frac1{1+\frac13}=\frac34.\\
$$
So $4S/3=3/4$, i.e. $S=9/16$.

Comment: I really like this solution, a really elegant way to solve the problem. However, I would've never thought about this approach.

Comment: Neither would I, my tendency would have been to use the power series approach. But it is true that's unnecessarily sophisticated: many students know geometric series without any knowledge of power series. Good thing is that now you and I both know the trick :)